# If height of image is greater than height of div then the bottom of the image is hidden, what if I want to hide the top?

Tags: html, css

If height of image is greater than height of div then image goes downward then what I do that it goes Upward

Comment: please share your code and also clearly explain your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean is, that the image is being "cut off" at the bottom, but what if you wanted it to show the bottom and not the top?

If so, you can use a negative margin to move the image around within the `<div>`.

```
/* Moves the element 10px upwards */
#mydiv1 {margin-top:-10px;}
```

more info here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/